# Moving file system from WSL1 to WSL2

Tags: filesystems, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I just installed WSL2 on my Windows 10 computer running Ubuntu 20.04. I already have WSL1 with Ubuntu 18.04 with a plethora of files and functions that I'd now like to use with my system in WSL2. I moved a single numpy folder over and my `.bashrc` script over as well. However, now whenever I try to move over a new folder, my command line tells me

`-bash: cd: rootfs/david/home/*folder name*: Permission Denied`

I've tried using sudo cd, but that gives me an error as well. I'm copying over the content using the directory location on windows, i.e.

```
cd /mnt/c/User/*User Name*/AppDate/Local/Packages/CanonicalGroupLimited.Ubuntu18.04onWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc/LocalState/rootfs/...
```

Did I screw something up in WSL2 setup? All I ultimately want to do is get the setup I had in WSL1 environment working in my WSL2 setup.

Comment: WSL seems to suffer with file-permissions that are out of its control. They are on he host system.

Comment: If you cd to `/mnt/c/User/*User Name*/AppDate/Local/Packages/CanonicalGroupLimited.Ubuntu18.04onWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc/LocalState/rootfs/...` one directory at a time, on which directory does the cd fail?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick It won't let me do anything in `./rootfs/`. I try to cd to that directory and I don't have permission, no tab complete or anything. If I verbatim write the path to a subdirectory, it still says I have no permission.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whatever I understood from your question is that you want to convert your WSL1 system to WSL2 system.

First to check the name of the distribution ("Ubuntu 10.04" must be a typo in the question).

```
wsl --list --verbose
```

Note the name of the distribution you want to convert to WSL2 and use the following command to convert:

```
wsl --set-version <distribution name> 2
```

The number written at the end of the command is the WSL version. You can write either `1` or `2` there.

Comment: So my WSL1 is in Ubuntu 18.04 and my WSL2 is in Ubuntu 20.04, I would like to using a WSL environment in Ubuntu 20.04. If I go to my WSL1 environment and do this, it will still be in 18.04, correct?

Comment: if you convert your WSL version of Ubuntu 18.04 from 1 to 2, it will still stays the same Ubuntu 18.04. So yes it is correct.

Comment: So I ended up converting my WSL 1 distribution from Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04, then I switched that over from WSL 1 to WSL 2. I don't know why the tutorial I first looked up had me set up a new WSL environment to run WSL 2.

Comment: glad it solved your problem.